# Problema con la copia de SSH

Tags: linux, github, terminal, ssh

Quiero vincular mi llave SSH a mi GitHub pero, al copiar el id me salta el siguiente error, agradecería si alguien me pudiese ayudar.

> ssh-copy-id "aqui va mi correo" /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of
> key(s) to be installed: "/home/calvarenga96/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
>
> /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s),
> to filter out any that are already installed

> /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host gmail.com port 22: >Network is unreachable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El comando `ssh-copy-id` copia una llave pública a un host. La sintaxis es

```
ssh-copy-id [-i ~/.ssh/llave.pub] user@host
```

Donde la llave, cuando no usas el parámetro `-i` es `id_rsa.pub` y `user@host` indica con qué usuario conectarse a qué host para subir esa llave.

Si tú pones

```
ssh-copy-id calvarenga@gmail.com
```

El comando intentará subir tu llave pública `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` conectándose por SSH a `gmail.com`, con el usuario `calvarenga`. El host de gmail nunca ha tenido el puerto 22 abierto así que ssh no podrá siquiera probar tu acceso.

---

Si lo que quieres es manejar tus repos con su dirección ssh y no https, para evitar ingresar tus credenciales en cada pull, push o fetch, entonces tienes que empezar por añadir tu llave pública a github en

[Settings -> SSH and GPG Keys -> Add New](https://github.com/settings/ssh/new)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí se pega el contenido de tu `/home/calvarenga96/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

Hecho esto, puedes probar si funcionó con

```
ssh git@github.com
```

¿Te fijas que eso no es un correo sino una tupla [user, host]? De tener éxito esto imprimiría

```
Hi <TU LOGIN>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

(nótese que, según lo indicado en el mensaje, tampoco es factible usar `ssh-copy-id` para subir tu llave pública a github).

Si acaso se quisiera usar una llave específica para github que no está entre las llaves por defecto (que serían `id_rsa` e `identity`) entonces tienes que establecerla en tu `~/.ssh/config`.

```
       Host github.com
            HostName github.com
            User git
            IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github.key
            IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Donde `~/.ssh/github.key` es la llave privada. Previamente debes haber hecho ya el paso de inscribir la llave pública `~/.ssh/github.pub` en el panel de Github. (los nombres de los archivos dan igual. Es un ejemplo).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, me ha servido bastante.